# Input from variable and excel to oledb destination in ssis 2012

Tags: ssis-2012

I have a situation where I need to get data from excel sheet and sql table then store it into a single sql server table.

Below steps I have completed already,

1.In control flow, by using execute sql task, fetched data from sql and assigned it to variable.

- 2.Then added Data flow task in control flow.
- 3.In data flow added Excel source and oledb destination.

When I trying to edit oledb destination I can only able to see excel sheet columns,

How to I do get variables also in Oledb destination? or is there any other best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a merge join control inside of a data flow task.

Probably easier to change your execute sql task to be a second data source within your data flow task and then join on the key within a merge join control.

Be warned the merge join requires the data to be sorted.  If the data is sorted on input, you can tell SSIS that by setting the input / output properties of the advanced editor.  Otherwise, you can add a sort task after each data source.